# Chapter on any page, but recto after part

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, chapters, double-sided, parts

Using the book style, I need chapters to start on anypage (as in openany) BUT to be recto after a part (which is also recto).

fussy eh!

Answer (score 8):

You can redefine the `\chapter` command to suppress the `\cleardoublepage` command that is used when `openany` is not used and replace it with a simple `\clearpage`. Add these lines to the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapter{\clearpage
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Works perfectly thank you. Where would I find documentation that would allow me to do this sort of thing myself (that in itself is not a tex tome 8)

Comment: @Jasper: in this particular case, you need to be familiar with the `.cls` files (in your case, `book.cls`); it's always a good experience to take a look at them, to learn what each command is doing, and to experiment a little to change the default behaviour; of course, those changes and experiments must be done using copies of the original files and not changing the files themselves. A good LaTeX manual, of course, will always be of great help.

Comment: @Jasper Learning this sort of thing is done with a mixture of reading source code (often quite well documented by package authors within the package documentation) and trying things, in addition to reading real books.  And hanging around here, where you can definitely learn a lot.

Comment: Thanks guys. I will be bolder in the future. I have done some hacking on class files. It always feels like stabbing in the dark tho 8) (usually works tho). Cheers.